# How iterable of list[index] over same list works

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

Suppose I have a list **'A'** and I want to iterate through this list using **A[-1]**

```
A = [1,2,3,40,50]
for A[-1] in A:
    print(A[-1])
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
40
40
```

Can anyone please help me understand what is going on behind the scene? 
I have some understanding of how interables works but this one is confusing me.

Comment: what output did you expect ?

Comment: I was expecting 1,2,3,40,50

Comment: why would you not use `for B in A: print(B)` ? -- that would simply give you the expected output.

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: I have seen this in some coding challenge .

Comment: This question is a dupe but I cannot find the corresponding question.

Comment: @EricDuminil It will be helpful if you figure out the source. May be someone answered it there

Answer (score 3):

`for item in list` statement assigns each element in `list` to `item` in every iteration. When you type `A[-1]` instead `item`, it assigns element to `A[-1]`, and `A` list changes.

To understand better let's change your `for loop` without affecting result and code logic, and add an extra `print`.

```
A = [1,2,3,40,50]
for x in A:
    A[-1] = x
    print(A[-1])
    print(A)
```

Output:

```
1
[1, 2, 3, 40, 1]
2
[1, 2, 3, 40, 2]
3
[1, 2, 3, 40, 3]
40
[1, 2, 3, 40, 40]
40
[1, 2, 3, 40, 40]
```

As you see, in every iteration, last item of A changes. It overwrites the last element. At last iteration the one before the last item(`40`) becomes the last item.

Comment: you are correct,  I know it is giving this. But the question is why it is changing the last elements ? We didn't explicitly specify to change the last element. We only performed iteration. Is there any conceptual understanding of iteration which I am missing here ? Why it is overwriting the last element ?

Comment: @user110244: Because what comes after `for` is used for an assignment. It can be a variable, an element in a sequence. `for x in A:;  A[-1] = x` is really equivalent to `for A[-1] in A`.

Comment: @user110244 `for item in list` statement assigns each element in `list` to `item` in every iteration. When you type `A[-1]` instead `item`, it assigns element to `A[-1]`, and A list changes. I have used `x` for a better understanding.

Comment: Please include this in your answer to make it more clear. I will mark it as done. Thanks a lot Alperen  for clearing up the confusion